# Detecting which input is focused React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I'm using React Hooks. I want to check which input is focused. I have an object of dynamically generated inputs. The inputs will be selected and I want to have a button that will append a value to the input that is in focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add events on Focus and on Focus Lost.

[W3Schools Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_focusevent.asp)

```
 <input type="text" onFocus="this.props.onFocus()" onFocusOut="this.props.lostFocus()">
```

Answer (score 6):

**(Edit) Updated to a much better solution using React Hook**

Most solutions I've come across don't take into account when the form has no active element. Hence I came up with the following hook to cover this case.

```
const useActiveElement = () => {
  const [listenersReady, setListenersReady] = React.useState(false); /** Useful when working with autoFocus */
  const [activeElement, setActiveElement] = React.useState(document.activeElement);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onFocus = (event) => setActiveElement(event.target);
    const onBlur = (event) => setActiveElement(null);

    window.addEventListener("focus", onFocus, true);
    window.addEventListener("blur", onBlur, true);

    setListenersReady(true);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("focus", onFocus);
      window.removeEventListener("blur", onBlur);
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    activeElement,
    listenersReady
  };
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-thunder-59u55?file=/src/Form.js

That should make it easier for you to detect which form input is active.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onFocus` event.

```
function handleFocus(e) {
  // logic here
}
<input onFocus={handeFocus} />
```

If you want to change input value, you could also use `onChange` event and `value` attribute.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('')

function handleChange(e) {
  setValue(e.target.value)
}

function handleFocus(e) {
  // logic here
  setValue('input focused')
}
<input value={value} onChange={handleChange} onFocus={handeFocus} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help :)

```
import React,{useRef} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
    const  inputRef = useRef();
    const onButtonClick=()=>{
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" value="" ref={inputRef}/>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```