# What is the proper way to detect DOM ref changes inside a custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am writing a custom hook that accepts a `ref`. I would like to attach an event listener to this DOM node and remove the listener inside a cleanup function.

I started with something like this:

**useIsFocused.ts**

```js
function useIsFocused(elem: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>) {
  const [hasFocus, setHasFocus] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
    const watched = elem.current;

    function setFocus() {
      setHasFocus(true);
    }
    function removeFocus() {
      setHasFocus(false);
    }

    if (watched) {
      // set initial value
      if (watched === document.activeElement) {
        setHasFocus(true);
      }

      // watch
      watched.addEventListener('focusin', setFocus);
      watched.addEventListener('focusout', removeFocus);

      // cleanup
      return () => {
        watched.removeEventListener('focusin', setFocus);
        watched.removeEventListener('focusout', removeFocus);
      };
    }
  }, [elem]);
}
```

That worked at first. However, once we started conditionally rendering the input elem, it stopped working. As the DOM node is destroyed and re-created, the handlers are not being cleaned up or re-attaching to the new node. After some digging, I realized it is because of the way refs work, since they are not part of re-renders. Of course, the `useEffect` is not triggering if the `ref.current` value changes. Therefore, my hook isn't responding to the changes in the DOM node.

Ideally, I'd like to use it like this:

**App.tsx**

```js
function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const inputIsFocused = useIsFocused(inputRef);
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      { showInput &&
        <input type="text" value={search} ref={inputRef} />
      }
      <p>Is focused? {JSON.stringify(inputisFocused)} </p>
      <button onClick={()=> setShowInput((e) => !e)}>Toggle input</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is, **what is the proper way to make a reusable, custom hook that cleanly attaches a listener to a DOM node, reacts to changes (such as mounting/unmounting the node) and handles cleanup?** Emphasis on a clean DX implementation for the implementing component.

Related questions

- [Detecting which input is focused React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497193/detecting-which-input-is-focused-react-hooks) (this comes closest but attaches the listener to the window using the window `blur` and `focus` events with capturing)
- [How to rerender when refs change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600572/how-to-rerender-when-refs-change) (need to encapsulate in a hook)

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, `ref`s do not trigger re-render. However, applying a `ref` to a component (or HTML element) will update the `ref` on each re-render (asymptotically). So.... lets match the update cycle instead.

```
function useIsFocused(elem: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>) {
  const [hasFocus, setHasFocus] = useState(false)

  const setFocus = useCallback(() => setHasFocus(true), [])
  const removeFocus = useCallback(() => setHasFocus(false), [])
  useEffect(() => {
    const watched = elem.current

    if (watched) {
      // set initial value
      if (watched === document.activeElement) {
        setHasFocus(true)
      }

      // watch
      watched.addEventListener('focusin', setFocus)
      watched.addEventListener('focusout', removeFocus)

      // cleanup
      return () => {
        watched.removeEventListener('focusin', setFocus)
        watched.removeEventListener('focusout', removeFocus)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Apply the events on every re-render by removing the dependency array on `useEffect`

**Bonus tip** why don't you make the hook return a tupple `[refObject, hasFocus]`. Since you are in a custom hook, you can create a ref object within the hook

Comment: I'm going to try this, thank you! About the bonus tip, I did think about creating and returning a `ref` from inside the hook and I can see how that can be useful, but since this will be integrated into a form component that already uses refs for other purposes (validation, focus trapping, error handling) that would complicate the logic inside the component that implements the hook to share the ref between those who need it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest staying away from `useRef` and `useEffect` as much as possible.

**Example 1: `useState` only**

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

function useFocusManager() {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  const onFocus = () => setFocused(true);
  const onBlur = () => setFocused(false);

  return { focused, onFocus, onBlur };
}

function App() {
  const inputFocusManager = useFocusManager();
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Is focused? - {inputFocusManager.focused ? "yes" : "no"} </p>

      {showInput && (
        <div>
          <input
            type='text'
            onFocus={inputFocusManager.onFocus}
            onBlur={inputFocusManager.onBlur}
          />
        </div>
      )}

      <div>
        <button onClick={()=> setShowInput(() => !showInput)}>Toggle input</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Example 2: with event listeners \wo `useRef` (upon request)**

Switching `useRef` to `useState` to trigger re-render to trigger `useEffect` to add event listeners when `inputRef` is assigned.

`useRef` doesn't provide re-render capability by design.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function useIsFocused(elemRef: HTMLInputElement | undefined) {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  function setFocus() {
    setFocused(true);
  }

  function removeFocus() {
    setFocused(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('elemRef', elemRef);

    if (elemRef) {
      elemRef.addEventListener('focusin', setFocus);
      elemRef.addEventListener('focusout', removeFocus);

      return () => {
        elemRef.removeEventListener('focusin', setFocus);
        elemRef.removeEventListener('focusout', removeFocus);
      };
    }
  }, [elemRef]);

  return focused;
}

function App() {
  const [inputRef, setInputRef] = useState<HTMLInputElement>();
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(true);
  const isInputFocused = useIsFocused(inputRef);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Is focused? - {isInputFocused ? "yes" : "no"} </p>
      {showInput && <input ref={(ref) => setInputRef(ref ?? undefined)} type='text' />}
      <button onClick={()=> setShowInput(() => !showInput)}>Toggle input</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Example 3: with event listeners \w `useRef` (upon request)**

`resetCounter` update triggers re-render which triggers `useEffect` which adds new event listeners

```js
import { RefObject, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

function useIsFocused(elemRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [resetCounter, setResetCounter] = useState(0);

  function reset() {
    setResetCounter(resetCounter + 1);
  }

  function setFocus() {
    setFocused(true);
  }

  function removeFocus() {
    setFocused(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('elemRef', elemRef.current);

    elemRef.current?.addEventListener('focusin', setFocus);
    elemRef.current?.addEventListener('focusout', removeFocus);

    // cleanup
    return () => {
      console.log('cleanup');

      elemRef.current?.removeEventListener('focusin', setFocus);
      elemRef.current?.removeEventListener('focusout', removeFocus);
    };
  }, [resetCounter]);

  return [focused, reset] as const;
}

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(true);

  const [isInputFocused, resetInputFocused] = useIsFocused(inputRef);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Is focused? - {isInputFocused ? "yes" : "no"} </p>
      {showInput && <input ref={inputRef} type='text' />}
      <button
        onClick={()=> {
          setShowInput(() => !showInput);
          resetInputFocused();
        }}
      >
        Toggle input
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you expand on why you suggest staying away from `useRef` and `useEffect` as much as possible? As I stated, I'm looking for solutions that encapsulate the attaching/detaching of event listeners inside of a hook. The component shouldn't have to do any that setup

Comment: I've updated the post upon request

Comment: Appreciate the options. Since this hook will be reused across many components, the simplest implementation signature wins (w/o sacrificing performance). So far option 3 seems the best DX. Is it necessary for the implementing component to have to manage a separate reset variable? Or can this further be encapsulated inside the hook?

Comment: the `reset` function has to be triggered outside the hook by the actor that causes the input to change its `ref`